# Method parameterizedTimerTrigger method not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins job with custom parameters on cron definition. How do I do that with job-dsl plugin?

I've tried this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42893
but my build fails because the methods parameterizedTimerTrigger & parameterizedSpecification can't be found.

I'm using Job DSL plugin 1.70 & parameterized trigger plugin 0.5

```
job('jenkins-node-respawn') {
    triggers {
        parameterizedTimerTrigger{
            parameterizedSpecification('CRON ELIMINATED 4 SIMPLICITY')
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL) syntax is only available when running in Jenkins, not in the playground and in the CLI runner.